# Core search, when only one result, open result

Tags: 7, search

Is there a simple way to accomplish the feature in the title ?
When a search results in one result, don't show the result but go directly to the node.

Answer (score 0):

As I see the only way is use hook menu alter for this item

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function search_menu() {
  $items['search'] = array(
    'title' => 'Search',
    'page callback' => 'search_view',
    'access callback' => 'search_is_active',
    'type' => MENU_SUGGESTED_ITEM,
    'file' => 'search.pages.inc',
  );
```

I propose to replace page callback "search_view" to your own and put there your logic.